# bash echo time date format

Tags: bash, shell

I have tested the format I need however I am unable to get the echo output, try put the quote around the different position.

```
[root@]# date '+%B %V %T.%3N:'
July 29 21:01:24.766:
```

```
echo 'date ’+%B %V %T.%3N:’ %LINK-3-UPDOWN: Interface Port-channel1, changed state to up'
```

expected output

```
July 29 21:01:24.766: %LINK-3-UPDOWN: Interface Port-channel1, changed state to up'
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do:

```
tm=$(date '+%B %V %T.%3N:')
echo "${tm} %LINK-3-UPDOWN: Interface Port-channel1, changed state to up"
```

Prints:

```
July 29 09:22:23.3N: %LINK-3-UPDOWN: Interface Port-channel1, changed state to up
```

Note the double `"` vs single `'`. Only strings in double quotes are interpolated in the shell:

```
bash-5.1$ s1='hello'
bash-5.1$ s2='there'
bash-5.1$ echo "${s1} ${s2}"
hello there
```

vs:

```
bash-5.1$ echo '${s1} ${s2}'
${s1} ${s2}
```

If you want the whole thing in one line:

```
echo "$(date '+%B %V %T.%3N:') %LINK-3-UPDOWN: Interface Port-channel1, changed state to up"
```

Or modify your `date` format string:

```
date '+%B %V %T.%3N: %%LINK-3-UPDOWN: Interface Port-channel1, changed state to up'
```

Comment: Hi dawg, thanks for the quick response, possible to use one line command instead of using a variable?

Comment: dawg, thanks and this is very close to what I need, one thing is how to make the month display 3 letter abbreviation like Jul.

Comment: Use `$(date '+%b %V %T.%3N:')` for the abbreviated month.

Answer (score 3):

You don't actually need `echo`. Let `date` write everything:

```
$ date '+%B %V %T.%3N %%LINK-3-UPDOWN: Interface Port-channel1, changed state to up'
July 29 09:34:15.874 %LINK-3-UPDOWN: Interface Port-channel1, changed state to up
```

Technically, you don't even need `date`, if you are willing to sacrifice the fraction of a second in the timestamp:

```
$ printf '%(%B %V %T)T %s\n' -1 "%LINK-3-UPDOWN: Interface Port-channel1, changed state to up"
July 29 09:36:40 %LINK-3-UPDOWN: Interface Port-channel1, changed state to up
```

(`bash` doesn't support `%N` in its implementation of `printf`. `%(...)T` formats an integer number of seconds according to `...`, with `-1` representing the current time.)

Comment: I need the millisecond and I use echo to pipe to nc, this is the full command.

echo 'date ’+%B %V %T.%3N:”’ %LINK-3-UPDOWN: Interface Port-channel1, changed state to up'  | nc -v -u -w 1 127.0.0.1 514

Answer (score 0):

Characters inside single quotes are a static string, always. If you want to execute a shell command, you need a command substitution, usually inside double quotes:

```sh
echo "$(date ’+%B %V %T.%3N:’) %LINK-3-UPDOWN: Interface Port-channel1, changed state to up"
```

However, that's basically just a [useless use of `echo`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#echo).

```sh
date ’+%B %V %T.%3N: %%LINK-3-UPDOWN: Interface Port-channel1, changed state to up'
```

Notice how you need to double any literal `%` characters in the `date` format string.